# I am getting an error 500, while i am trying to show all the products that exist in my database using SpringBoot

Tags: spring, spring-boot, frontend, thymeleaf, backend

when i create a product and fill out the details in the create_product.html page when i click on add button, it should direct me to the Products.html page which I will show all the products but I am getting an error when I transferred me to the Products.html page. However, when i check my database table I found that the product had been added.

ProductController Class

```
 @Controller
public class ProductsController {


    //adding the service layer of the product

    @Autowired
    private  ProductService productService;

    @Autowired
    private CategoriesRepository categoriesRepository;

    public  ProductsController(ProductService productService,CategoriesRepository categoriesRepository )
    {
        super();
        this.productService = productService;
        this.categoriesRepository = categoriesRepository;
    }

    // models

    @ModelAttribute("category")
    public List<Categories> initializeCategories(){
        List<Categories> categories = categoriesRepository.findAll();
        return categories ;
    }

    @ModelAttribute("product")
    public Products products()
    {
        return new Products();
    }


    /////////////////////////////////// handllers


    //request to list all the products
    @RequestMapping("/products/all_products")
    public String listProducts(Model model)
    {
        model.addAttribute("product",productService.getAllProducts());

        return "Products/products";

    }


    //request to show the form to create a product // when u are accessing the http request u will access that one coz it will show the form and then the Save method will do the action
    @GetMapping("/products/new/product")
    public String createProductForm(Model model)
    {
        //Create product object
        Products product = new Products();

        model.addAttribute("product",product); // product is the object from products Entityclass

        return "Products/create_product";
    }

    //request to create/save a product
    @RequestMapping(value = "/products/create_product",method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String saveProduct(@ModelAttribute("product") Products product) // Products is the name of the Entity class and creating a productObjcet from it
    {
        productService.saveProduct(product);

        return "redirect:/products/all_products";
    }

    @GetMapping("/products/edit/{id}")
    public String editProductForm(@PathVariable long id, Model model)
    {
        model.addAttribute("product",productService.getProductById(id));
        return "Products/edit_product";
    }

    //request to update product
    @RequestMapping(value = "/products/update_product/{id}",method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public String updateProduct(@PathVariable Long id, @ModelAttribute("product") Products product, Model model) // model Attribute is the data taken from the html file by the user
    {
        //get product from the db by id

        Products existingProduct = productService.getProductById(id);

        existingProduct.setProduct_id(id);

        existingProduct.setProduct_name(product.getProduct_name());

        existingProduct.setProduct_price(product.getProduct_price());

        existingProduct.setProduct_category(product.getProduct_category());

        existingProduct.setProduct_quantity(product.getProduct_quantity());

        existingProduct.setProduct_Section(product.getProduct_Section());

        existingProduct.setProduct_ExpDate(product.getProduct_ExpDate());


        //updating the product
        productService.updateProduct(existingProduct);

        return "redirect:/products/all_products";

    }

    //request to Delete product
    @GetMapping("/products/delete_product/{id}")
    public String deleteProduct(@PathVariable long id)
    {
        productService.deleteProduct(id);

        return "redirect:/products/all_products";
    }
}
```

Categories Entity Class:

```
  @Entity
@Data
public class Categories {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long categories_id;

    private String categoryName;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "product_category",fetch = FetchType.LAZY) //the name of the variable in the other class
    private Set<Products> product_category = new HashSet<>();


    public Categories(String categoryName, Set<Products> product_category) {
        this.categoryName = categoryName;
        this.product_category = product_category;
    }

    public Categories() {
    }


    public String getCategoryName() {
        return categoryName;
    }

    public void setCategoryName(String categoryName) {
        this.categoryName = categoryName;
    }
}
```

Product Entity class :

```
 @Entity
@Table(name = "Products")
@Data
public class Products {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long product_id;

    private String product_name;

    private BigDecimal product_price;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "categories_id") //the name of the column in the other class and that name will be a column in the class
    private Categories product_category;

    private String product_quantity;

    private String product_Section;

    private String product_ExpDate;


    public Products()
    {
        super();
    }

    public Products(String product_name, BigDecimal product_price,String product_quantity,Categories product_category ,String product_Section,String product_ExpDate) {
        this.product_name = product_name;
        this.product_category = product_category;
        this.product_price = product_price;
        this.product_quantity = product_quantity;
        this.product_Section = product_Section;
        this.product_ExpDate = product_ExpDate;
    }
```

ProductService Class:

```
    @Service
public class ProductServiceImp implements ProductService {


    //productRepository class
    private ProductRepository productRepository;

    public ProductServiceImp(ProductRepository productRepository) {
        this.productRepository = productRepository;
    }

    @Override
    public List<Products> getAllProducts() {
        return this.productRepository.findAll();
    }

    @Override
    public Products saveProduct(Products product) {
        return this.productRepository.save(product);
    }

    @Override
    public Products updateProduct(Products product) {
        return this.productRepository.save(product);
    }

    @Override
    public void deleteProduct(long id) {
        this.productRepository.deleteById(id);
    }

    public Products getProductById(long id)
    {
       return productRepository.findById(id).get();
    }
}
```

CreateProduct.html page:

```
 <form th:action="@{/products/create_product}" method="post" th:object="${product}">

            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="control-label" for="product_name"> Product Name </label> <input
                    id="product_name" class="form-control" th:field="*{product_name}"
                    required autofocus="autofocus" />
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="control-label" for="product_price"> Price </label> <input
                    id="product_price" class="form-control" th:field="*{product_price}" required
                    autofocus="autofocus" />
            </div>

            <div class="col-1.5">
                <label th:for="category"> Category </label>
                <select class="form-control form-control-sm" id="category" name="product_category">
                    <option value=""> Select Category </option>
                    <option th:each = "category: ${category}"
                            th:value="${category.categories_id}"
                            th:text="${category.categoryName}"

                    > <!--th:field="*{product_category}"-->
                    </option>
                </select>
            </div>

            <br>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="control-label" for="product_quantity"> Quantity </label> <input
                    id="product_quantity" class="form-control" type="text"
                    th:field="*{product_quantity}" required autofocus="autofocus" />
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="control-label" for="product_Section"> Section </label> <input
                    id="product_Section" class="form-control" type="text"
                    th:field="*{product_Section}" required autofocus="autofocus" />
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="control-label" for="product_ExpDate"> Expire Date </label> <input
                    id="product_ExpDate" class="form-control" type="text"
                    th:field="*{product_ExpDate}" required autofocus="autofocus" />
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Save</button>
            </div>
        </form>
```

products.html page

```
<table class = "table table-striped table-bordered">
            <thead class = "table-dark">
            <tr>
                <th> Category </th>
                <th> Product Name </th>
                <th> Product Price </th>
                <th> Product Quantity </th>
                <th> Product Section </th>
                <th> Product Expiry Date </th>
                <th> Edit </th>
                <th> Delete </th>
            </tr>
            </thead>

            <tbody>

            <tr th:each = "product: ${product}"> <!-- this attribute to list up products  -->

                <td th:text="${product.product_category}" ></td>
                <td th:text="${product.product_name}"></td>
                <td th:text="${product.product_price}"></td>
                <td th:text="${product.product_quantity}" ></td>
                <td th:text="${product.product_Section}" ></td>
                <td th:text="${product.product_ExpDate}" ></td>

                <td> <center> <a th:href="@{/products/edit/{id}(id=${product.product_id})}" style="color: green"> Edit </a> </center> </td>

                <td> <center> <a th:href="@{/products/delete_product/{id}(id=${product.product_id}) }" style="color: red"> Delete </a> </center> </td>

            </tr>

            </tbody>

        </table>
```

FullTrace Error:

```
    This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.

Wed Oct 20 03:45:45 EDT 2021
There was an unexpected error (type=Internal Server Error, status=500).
No message available
java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at com.mysql.cj.NativeSession.execSQL(NativeSession.java:696)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeInternal(ClientPreparedStatement.java:930)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeQuery(ClientPreparedStatement.java:1003)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyPreparedStatement.executeQuery(ProxyPreparedStatement.java:52)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyPreparedStatement.executeQuery(HikariProxyPreparedStatement.java)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.extract(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:57)
    at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.internal.AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.getResultSet(AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.java:390)
    at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.internal.AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.executeQueryStatement(AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.java:163)
    at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.internal.AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.executeLoad(AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.java:104)
    at org.hibernate.loader.collection.plan.AbstractLoadPlanBasedCollectionInitializer.initialize(AbstractLoadPlanBasedCollectionInitializer.java:87)
    at org.hibernate.persister.collection.AbstractCollectionPersister.initialize(AbstractCollectionPersister.java:710)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultInitializeCollectionEventListener.onInitializeCollection(DefaultInitializeCollectionEventListener.java:76)
    at org.hibernate.event.service.internal.EventListenerGroupImpl.fireEventOnEachListener(EventListenerGroupImpl.java:99)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.initializeCollection(SessionImpl.java:2163)
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection$4.doWork(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:589)
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.withTemporarySessionIfNeeded(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:264)
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.initialize(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:585)
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.read(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:149)
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentSet.hashCode(PersistentSet.java:458)
    at com.example.warehouseManagementSystem.Entities.Categories.hashCode(Categories.java:10)
    at com.example.warehouseManagementSystem.Entities.Products.hashCode(Products.java:10)
    at java.base/java.util.HashMap.hash(HashMap.java:340)
    at java.base/java.util.HashMap.put(HashMap.java:612)
    at java.base/java.util.HashSet.add(HashSet.java:221)
```

Comment: Can you add the code for `Categories` ? The `StackOverflowError` leads me to believe there might be some kind of endless loop that is happening. Probably because of one of the Lombok annotations in combination with the `Products` and `Categories` entities.

Comment: i just added the categories class Entity, plz lmk what do u think to solve the solution?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are using `@Data` from Lombok on your entity. Remove this and manually implement `equals()` and `hashCode` in a way that does not lead to a `StackOverflowError`. In most cases, you only want to check the primary key.

See https://www.wimdeblauwe.com/blog/2021/04/26/equals-and-hashcode-implementation-considerations/ for more info on how to correctly implement equals and hashcode.

See also https://thorben-janssen.com/lombok-hibernate-how-to-avoid-common-pitfalls/#Avoid_Data for more info on why you should be careful with Lombok and JPA/Hibernate.

Comment: i will update what i am getting now

Comment: If you want to use Lombok. and equals and hashcode is a problem the way to go is to define the fields equals and hashcode should generated from. e.g. ```@EqualsAndHashCode(of = {"yourFieldName"})```